# a browser cookie and a renewed cert issue

Tags: ssl, cookies

I logged in to my app and the TSL certificate has expired after 15 minutes. I renewed an expired certificate and I couldn't log in, however after clearing my browser's cookies
I was able to login again.

My questions

```
Why did I need to clear browser cookies to be able to log in?

Are cookies somehow related to TSL certificate / (-es)?

Do old cookies become invalid upon TSL certificate expiration?

Are these issues specific to a given situation or is it a common behavior that an expired certificate makes a cookie invalid or is it something else (perhaps, app specific)?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLS certificates and cookies have nothing in common, they are totally independent. Cookies may contain encrypted data but that might be tied to some other certificate or private/public-key but this is still independent from the TLS cert.

Comment: Thank you, for your response. am I right to say that that an encrypted piece in a cookie becomes invalid upon a cert renewal?

Comment: In theory it could be, but usually the cookie encryption is tied to some other cert/key. Bit it can also be that after re-deployment, the existing cookies get automatically invalidated.